# How to detect errors when running a process with Ruby and open3

Tags: ruby, process, jruby, dos

I created a helper method in Ruby using open3 to execute DOS commands from JRuby...

```
   def ShellUtils.execute_cmd(cmd)
        $ERRORS = ['Invalid type','Invalid path']
        out = nil
        err = nil
        Open3.popen3(cmd) {|stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr|
            out = stdout.read
            err = stderr.read
            unless err.nil?
                err = $ERRORS.detect {|e| err.include? e }
            end
            out.each {|line| logger.info "#{line}"} unless out.nil?
            err.each {|line| logger.error #{line}"} unless err.nil?

        }        
        return out, err
    end
```

If any part of the process being executed is invalid, an error message along with its usage is output. Below is the normal error output when executing the process in DOS, no JRuby or Ruby involved...

```
C:\PROJECTS\bin>import.bat -su -types ws,v
Invalid type. Valid ones are: folder, datasource...
Usage:
  import -f path-to-file [-s servers-file | -h server...
```

But when I execute `import.bat` using `ShellUtils.execute_cmd()` and JRuby, the log never captures the error message, `Invalid type. Valid ones are...`, I'm only seeing the usage output to the err log. I don't understand why since the usage, and error message, originate from `import.bat`.  I've checked both the `out` and `err` objects and neither of them contain the error string.

I just need to detect the error message to signal a failure of the process to the caller, but without that string in the err log it's difficult to know what the hecks going on.

Comment: try redirecting both stdout and stderr when running import.bat in DOS (import.bat ... > o.txt 2> e.txt), does it still display anything?

Comment: Yes, I see the error message `Invalid type...` in `e.txt`, and the usage is in `o.txt`.

Comment: @VictorMoroz What did that test prove? I've new to Ruby, so any insight is appreciated, thx

Comment: I was thinking of strange ways Windows can display output. But if it can be redirected, obviously it's a standard one and should be caught by `popen3`. Btw, are you using `win32/open3`?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

After looking at your method a bit I think you have a mistake. Can you try this:

```
def ShellUtils.execute_cmd(cmd)
  out = nil
  err = nil
  Open3.popen3(cmd) {|stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr|
    out = stdout.read
    err = stderr.read

    unless err.nil?
      err = err.split("\n")
      puts err.inspect
      err = err.select {|e| e =~ /Invalid/ }
    end

    out.each {|line| logger.info "#{line}"} unless out.nil?
    err.each {|line| logger.error "#{line}"} unless err.nil?

  }

  return out, err
end
```

Not so much a solution as a thought. You might want to try systemu. It's worked pretty well for me with jruby:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'systemu'

cmd = "#{File.expand_path('../', __FILE__)}/import.bat -su -types ws,v "

status, stdout, stderr = systemu cmd
p [ status, stdout, stderr ]
```

Comment: Also I assume: err.each {|line| logger.error #{line}"} unless err.nil? should be: err.each {|line| logger.error "#{line}"} unless err.nil? note the missing "

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your process hasn't yet written to the error stream at that point. Try waiting for it to finish before reading its output:

```
Open3.popen3 cmd do |stdin, stdout, stderr, thread|
  thread.join  # Wait for the process to finish
  output, error = stdout.read, stderr.read
  # ...
end
```

Comment: It's not necessary in MacOSX as `read` is blocking, not sure what happens in Windows.

Comment: The `join` method is not available in JRuby 1.8? `NoMethodError undefined method join' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: @RaffiM, in Ruby 1.8, the [`Open3::popen3`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen3) method does not pass a `Thread` to the block. Extra block parameters are implicitly set to `nil`, which does not respond to `join`. [**Use Ruby 1.9**](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2011/10/06/plans-for-1-8-7/).